# How to translate a loop to multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize some code. So here's what I am trying to do:

I have a test_cases function that takes several args, creates and tests some cases on a 3rd party app. I have 33 of such tests. Currently, I set up a for loop with a index counter that runs each of the tests. Each test returns an array which is then compared against the 'expected values' array for that array. If the values are not right, the index is noted and I do other stuff.

I am trying to parallelize such that many tests run simultaneously and I get the index numbers where the test failed. I have explored multiprocessing but do not understand it right. Do I use `Pool` or `Process`?

Examples I looked at online showed basic cases but I have difficulty in translating that knowledge to this scale. So my question is how do I set up multiprocessing for each test so that I get an array back to compare against expected vals?

Comment: What testing framework are you using? `pytest` has `pytest-xdist` for executing tests in parallel.

Comment: It sounds like MTguy wrote his own framework. If that's accurate, go checkout pytest, it provides excellent support for the types of things you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! As in the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) you want to first create a pool object with something like Pool(2) if you have 2 cores available. If you do this with a with... as... block you can then use the object within the block and it will be cleaned up after. The example below is from the docs and applies the function "f" in parallel to the items in the list by using the pool object's map method. You may want "starmap" which can process a list of tuples and allows f to have multiple arguments - check it out in the documentation.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```